# What are the implications of constraint locality in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm a bit confused as to how constraints are managed in Postgres.

The source of this confusion is a diff between the output from two runs of pg_dump (on different boxes) that *should* be identical. The lone difference between the dumps is a change in default tablespace prior to setting up a number of constraints. To be extra clear here, no tables are created after the change in tablespace, only constraints.

I'm trying to determine if this actually affects anything about the constraints themselves. My main question:

- `pg_constraint` has a `conislocal` boolean attribute. Does this indicate whether the constraint is stored in the same tablespace as the table with which it is associated?

Some followup questions:

- Assuming the prior question is true, if all constraints are local, and the affected dumpfile only changes the tablespace prior to creating the constraints (ie all of the actual tables are in the 'correct' tablespace) will there be any difference between the layout of the database when restoring the two dumpfiles?
- Any hazardous guesses as to what could account for the change in default tablespace between the two instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraint locality has nothing to do with tablespaces; a local constraint is one that is defined on a partition of a partitioned parent table that  itself has no identical constraint -- it is a *logical* locality.

You don't say what *types* of constraints you're talking about. PKs and unique constraints will cause creation of missing underlying indexes, which can obviously be affected by the change of the default tablespace.

Comment: Thanks, you definitely answered the main thrust of my question. If you have a moment for an additional request for clarification... Are table partitions an overloaded term? I think of table partitions as logically segmented (by date for instance) and none of these tables are partitioned in that manner. Is there some other partitioning I should be aware of?

Comment: Non-partitioned tables don't have "parents", so all their constraints will be local (`pg_constraint.conislocal` = 't').

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.